# Как написать логическое условие в while?

Tags: c

Есть задача: закончить цикл, только когда будут значения 1 или 2. Написал вот такую программу:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a = 0;

    while ((a != 1) || (a != 2)) {
        printf("Please enter integer 1 or 2 ");
        scanf("%d", &a);
    }
    printf("That's all\n");
}
```

Но цикл сразу заканчивается, не могу понять почему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто запишите в

```
while(!(a == 1 || a == 2)) { ....
```

условие *обратное* к заданному. У Вас условие окончания (a == 1 || a == 2), вот и напишите его отрицание.

Comment: А еще полезно почитать про [законы де Моргана](http://ru.wikipedia.ru/Законы_де_Моргана)

Comment: 30 центов двумя монетками. при этом одна из них не 5 центов =)

Comment: 10 и 20? 15 и 15? Не забывайте, что мы здесь не знаем, где, в какое время и какие центы используются

Comment: Очевидно 25 и 5. А что еще хотите?

Comment: @avp, не очевидно, а туманно. Я ж говорю, что нужно точно знать про какую валюту и какого периода времени идет речь. Попробуйте нонешними копейками набрать 30 копеек двумя монетками...

Comment: Вопрос был о центах (причем без  уточнения, каких именно (страна, год)), а не о нонешних копейках.

Comment: Да, 25 и 5 (бывает еще 10 центовик, который не поможет). Разница тут в операторах || и &&. "Одна из них не 5" или "ни одна из них не 5". Очевидно ТС раскрыл скобки из ответа без изменения дизъюнкции на конъюнкцию. Обычная ошибка в логике предикатов.

Comment: О пользе изучения математики.

Answer (score 0):

> Но цикл сразу заканчивается, не могу понять почему.

Так и знал, что ты меня обманываешь!.. В) пять минут в твой код пялился.

Ты написал: выполнять, **пока** ((А не равно 1) **или** (А не равно 2)) - результат этого выражения всегда **ИСТИНА**, ибо даже когда ты вводишь 1, она не равна 2 и выполнение продолжается, т.е. это бесконечный цикл (проверено экспериментально)

В твоём варианте кода надо ИЛИ на И поменять. Но предложенное **avp**'ом более рационально, т.к. содержит меньше логических операций (конечно, не существенно, но дело принципа)

Comment: @Mike, мое предложение проще,  прежде всего потому, что оно совпадает с обычной человеческой логикой.